# What do we do with the return value of __get_free_pages

Tags: c, linux-kernel

What is the purpose of returning the memory address of a first byte of first page allocated? What do we do with the return value? How can I save values in the allocated memory? I know I miss the point of that functions.

```c
static unsigned long addr;

static int __init sys_module_init(void)
{
    addr = __get_free_pages(GFP_KERNEL, 0); // 1 << order
    return 0;
}
```

```c
static void __exit sys_module_exit(void)
{
    free_pages(addr, 0);
}
```

Comment: you want to know how to store a value in memory if you only know the address of the memory...?

Comment: @user253751 I don't know how can I use the address of the allocated memory in order to store data in it.

Comment: It's basically like `malloc`. You know what `malloc` is and how to use it?

Comment: The Linux source assumes that values of type `void *` and `unsigned long` are interchangeable. Some functions prefer one over the other depending on the expected usage. You can use type casts to convert the values. I guess it must be fairly common for callers of `__get_free_pages` to convert the returned address to a page number using `>> PAGE_SHIFT` so `unsigned long` was more convenient.

Comment: @Devolus Yeah of course, but when I try to use `char *` instead of `unsigned long` it throwing me an error. The return value of `__get_free_pages` is `unsigned long`.

Comment: `char *p = (char *)__get_free_pages()`

Comment: @Devolus Oh okay, so by default it just returns the address of the memory? Also, how can I access the address after that cast, just use `(unsigned long)p`?

Comment: `it just returns the address of the memory` That's what the documentation says, so I would go for that. If you cast it to a pointer, you can simply use the pointer, like I showed above.

Comment: Yeah seems like it works good

Comment: @IanAbbott Thank you! Solved my issue

Comment: @HassanNasrallah "The address of the memory" is literally what a pointer is

Answer (score 0):

The return value of __get_free_pages is the virtual address of the first byte on that page but it is typecasted to unsigned long.
Here is its definition from mm/page_alloc.c

```
unsigned long __get_free_pages(gfp_t gfp_mask, unsigned int order)
{
    struct page *page;

    page = alloc_pages(gfp_mask & ~__GFP_HIGHMEM, order);
    if (!page)
        return 0;
    return (unsigned long) page_address(page);
}
```

page_address(page) will simply return page->virtual.

The usage of return address: It could be used as any other virtual address after type-casting of the required type. To use a char *, just do like this.

```
unsigned long page_ptr;
char *byte_add;
page_ptr =  __get_free_pages(GFP_KERNEL, 0); // allocate just one page
byte_add = (char *) page_ptr;
```